# Pointer Arithmetic in C while equating two pointers

Tags: c

Kindly note that I had gone through several questions in stackoverflow related to pointers but I could not get similar kind of question which I am about to ask. It may be that question already exists and I dont know proper tag to search. here is my doubt in C programming.

First program

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int main(void) {
        int i,j;
        int **p = (int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
        p[0] = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
        p[1] = p[0];
        for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                p[i][j] = i + j;
        printf("%d",p[0][0]);
        return 0;
    }
```

Output is 1

Second Program

7th line is changed to

```
p[1] = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
```

Output is 0;

Both the programs almost look similar but they are giving different results. I am just not able to understand whats going underneath. Can anyone please help.

Comment: Long story short. In the first case. There is a single memory location allocated where the data is held. In the second case. Memory is allocated twice so 2 separate memory locations exist holding the data. Hope you can figure out the rest.

Comment: There is no pointer arithmetic in this code. Arithmetic meaning `+` or `-`. Pointer arithmetic meaning `ptr + something` etc.

Comment: @Lundin thanks I changed the topic subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`p[1] = p[0];` makes `p[1]` (which is a pointer) point to the *same* memory as `p[0]` points to.

`p[1] = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));` dynamically allocates *new* memory and lets `p[1]` point to that.

So if you modify `p[1][i]` you are modifying the same object as `p[0][i]` in the first, but not the second, case.

Comment: So third time when the loop starts p[1][0] it actually alters the value of p[0][0] which was stored as 0 during first iteration.

Comment: @AmitRay Yes. It alters the object that both `p[0][0]` and `p[1][0]` refer to.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot it is not maths arithmetic but pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @AmitRay It doesn't actually have anything to do with pointer arithmetic. Just with what a pointer is in general. "*Pointer arithmetic*" refers to addition and subtraction on pointer values, which is what e.g. `p[1]` implicitly does (it is the same as `*(p+1)`). It does not refer to arithmetic operations on integer values just because they are accessed through pointers.

Comment: agreed sir. I was actually referring to equal to sign. If a=c and b=a, so a=b=c but second case a=c and b=c but a!=b!=c as c is different in both cases. its having different address. Anyways thanks for pointing me to right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short. In the first case. There is a single memory location allocated where the data is held. In the second case. Memory is allocated twice so 2 separate memory locations exist holding separate data. Hope you can figure out the rest